# hyperref token not allowed warning, possible bug?

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I currently am using the `hyperref` package and I'm currently getting a lot of error messages. Currently all of the chapter and section titles give this same error. I decided to try make a minimum example and currently:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{The}

\end{document}
```

Is giving me the following warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                \kern 5.0pt
(hyperref)                replaced by space on input line 18.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing '\noindent' on input line 18.
```

Is this a bug with the `hyperref` package or is this just a result of me not setting up things properly? How do I go about either fixing this or silencing the warning messages?

Comment: `\part{The}` wouldn't produce those warnings. Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the messages.

Comment: @cgnieder, This is producing exactly those warnings on my setup here. This was a minimal example.

Comment: No. A MWE starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. This doesn't produce said warnings: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{The}
\end{document}`

Comment: @cgnieder, edited as per request to include the entire example file I ran this from.

Comment: It seems to be a bug related to `amsbook`, as discussed in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/latexusersgroup/kgRcnMoDuhI/3ZjLZmmUYJcJ). You may want to ignore the warning, if it is not affecting the desired output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not really a bug, but an innocuous “feature”. You can cure it by disabling the offending commands during bookmark preparation:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\enspace\empty  % this causes the warning for \kern
  \let\noindent\empty % this causes the warning for \indent
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\part{The}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\pdfstringdefDisableCommand` has precisely this purpose: to add definitions for commands that make no sense in bookmarks. Several commands are already redefined to safe version (for instance `\<space>`), but it would slow down compilation if all commands one can think of were included. So only the most common ones are redefined, others can be added when needed.

---

As an aside, note that `\frontmatter` should be preferred to `\pagenumbering{roman}` for the front matter of the document. There's no need of `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\mainmatter`.

Comment: With `\quad` in a Section title, `hyperref` throws a "Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string", which is suppressed by, in the preamble after invoking `hyperref`, `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\hskip\empty}`.

Comment: @JosephHarriott I'd prefer `\let\quad\space`

Comment: `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\quad\space}` doesn't suppress the "Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string".

Comment: @JosephHarriott Doh!

Comment: I am still getting the `\kern` warning, for seemingly innocent `\chapter{Introduction} \label{chapter.introduction}`...

Comment: @zyy Not with the code in the answer

Comment: @egreg Even after I added the part `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`.